# How to invoke a function inside a variable?

Tags: javascript

I am playing with module patterns in JavaScript in order to reduce the number of global variables in my code as that is considered bad practice in JavaScript.

For example, I have this simple function to validate email from an input:

```
var checkEmail = (function() {
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail'),
        emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    function validateEmail() {
        if (userEmail.value.search(emailRegEx) === -1) {
            console.log('Invalid email!');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Correct!');
        }
    }
    userEmail.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
})();
```

How can I invoke this function?

Comment: are you seeing any error , it seems you are already invoking it in addEventListener

Comment: "How can I invoke this function?", You are using an IIFE  (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which already invokes itselfs. You return nothing so `checkEmail` will be `undefined`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to invoke the `validateEmail` function. The easiest way is to trigger the `keyup` event on the `userEmail` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var checkMail = function(){ ... }
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
function checkMail(){ ... }
```

so to call it, just use:

```
checkMail();
```

*edit*

I may have been too quick. What you have there is a closure, and another function inside it. It would work even without the `var checkEmail =` at the beginning – because it calls itself and adds a listener to the `keyup` event. If you wanted to have access to the inner `validateEmail` function, you would have to do this:

```
var checkEmail = (function() {
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail'),
        emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    function validateEmail() {
        if (userEmail.value.search(emailRegEx) === -1) {
            console.log('Invalid email!');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Correct!');
        }
    }
    userEmail.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);

    return validateEmail;
})();
```

You'd return the function itself, and now you could use `checkMail()` to call the inner function.

Comment: indeed, `return validateEmail` is just enough, despite it doesn't really makes much sense to add an event listener over and over, perhaps the logic of the whole situation has to be reseen. besides, it seems to be pointless to me declaring that as an IIAF

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I might have not explained well. What I was trying to do was to use the whole function inside checkEmail variable. As I can see, I don't need to invoke it. However do you think this is a good practice?

Comment: @brunodd This is a very modern technique in JavaScript, called closure. It is a great way to not have lots of function-specific variables polluting the global scope. Most js libraries nowadays use it in some form, so yes, it is good practice. Much more detailed and useful info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to call the `validateEmail` function specifically, you could return it:

```
var checkEmail = (function() {
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('contatoEmail'),
        emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    function validateEmail() {
        if (userEmail.value.search(emailRegEx) === -1) {
            console.log('Invalid email!');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Correct!');
        }
    }
    userEmail.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);

    return{
        validateEmail : validateEmail;
    }
})();
```

If your `checkEmail` variable is in the global scope, then `validateEmail` would be available in the global scope as well.

Answer (score 1):

`var checkEmail = (function() {})();` is an **anonymous function** expression that gets **invoked immediately**. It is called immediately invoked function expression (IIFE). Therefore there is no need to invoke it!

Comment: This is slightly misleading. `checkEmail` is not a function at all. It will be `undefined`. The un-named function is invoked by the way the code is written (sometimes known as IIFE).

Comment: "self-invoked" function is an old, inaccurate term. Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) is a much better term.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is called the **Revealing Module Pattern** . Practically this pattern should include  **init , render , and event binding functions** . When done correct you init function will launch your module.
Also you should be using **this** to store and reference all your variables to module ..

**Example :**

```
var checkEmail = (function() {

function init(){

    //Store all variables on module
    cacheDom();

    //Bind all user events click, keyup ect...
    bindEvents();

    //Resets form , clears input fields ect...basically sets app to default state
    render();

}

function cacheDom(){

      this.userEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail'),
        this.emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;


}

function bindEvents(){
 this.userEmail.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);

}

//Render sets the default state of app
function render(){

userEmail.innerHTML = " ";

}



function validateEmail() {
  console.log('keyed')
        if (userEmail.value.search(this.emailRegEx) === -1) {
            console.log('Invalid email!');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Correct!');

        //Resets state after success
        render()
        }

    }

   //Initializing module...email will be validated on keyup
  init();

})();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you. Yeah I am getting started with Module Patterns in JavaScript. For example, if I have another function that checks if all inputs are blank, should I that function inside checkEmail variable too?

Comment: Yes every action associated with the email form should be put inside the checkEmail  module .

Answer (score -1):

You already have. This:

```
var checkEmail = function() {
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail'),
        emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    function validateEmail() {
        if (userEmail.value.search(emailRegEx) === -1) {
            console.log('Invalid email!');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Correct!');
        }
    }
    userEmail.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
};

checkEmail();
```

Is the same as this:

```
(function() {
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail'),
        emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    function validateEmail() {
        if (userEmail.value.search(emailRegEx) === -1) {
            console.log('Invalid email!');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Correct!');
        }
    }
    userEmail.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
})();
```